# apply ID to a jquery mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile

when I apply an ID of "assets" to may jquery mobile page it has some strange behavior when I directly call it. for example http://localhost/Index.html#assets

any idea?

Comment: It's not very specific, Why it happens, I hope that you are using Page sections in Mobile Page, Make sure it has the proper ID, and You said you are directly calling the page section with the ID "assets" I don't get the point how you calling it and finally I could suggest you to consider `changePage()` or `loadPage()` where you can use the ID as a link and apply some cool transitions. Let me know is this helps  you or not. Happy day

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your id is correctly placed in the second page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">
      <a href="#assets" data-role="button" > Go To Assets </a>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="assets">
      Assets page.
</div>
```